# Gradle exclude local jar during testRunTime

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I've below situation here... My `Gradle jar` target needs `javaee-api-*.jar` as a `compile` time

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])

}
```

But, during `Gradle test` execution I need `dependencies` as below...

```
dependencies {

    compileOnly fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])

}
```

How should I exclude a jar during `testRunTime`?

Comment: why? You shouldn't include it in your end result so `compileOnly` should be for both.

Comment: Umm... that's the crazy thing here that I'm not getting... `compileOnly` breaks the `jar` target while `compile` breaks the `test` target :(

Comment: Is there a reason you are including a local jar and not reference the globally available `javaee-api` dependency? What is also interesting to know is how it fails in both cases and which additional dependencies you have.

Comment: Currently I'm migrating the local jar `ant` based project to `Gradle` and taking precautions to use very well defined tested jars from local repo but Yes soon I'm moving it to S3

Comment: I'd try some thing with configurations{ testRuntime.exclude fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])}

Comment: Not sure but getting error as `Could not find method exclude() for arguments [directory 'lib/connectors/oraclejavaee/javaee-api-6.0.jar'] on configuration ':testRuntime' of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I filtered out `javaee-api-*.jar` from `project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.filter`

added `javaee-api-*.jar` as a compile dependuncy

```
dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: '../lib', include: ['/**/javaee-api-*.jar'])

}
```

and

```
   sourceSets {

      ....
    
    test {
        runtimeClasspath = project.sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath.filter {
            !it.path.endsWith('oraclejavaee/javaee-api-6.0.jar')
        }
        java.srcDir project(':test-framework').file("src")
        resources.srcDirs project(':test-framework').file("config")
    }
  }
```

and adding `dependOn` in

```
test {
    dependsOn(testClasses)
    useTestNG() { //Tells Gradle to use TestNG
        useDefaultListeners = true // Tells TestNG to execute its default reporting structure
        suites 'test/testng.xml' //location of our suite.xml
    }
}
```